# Skipping lines of code after a flag is set

Tags: c#

I have a fairly large program (C#) that needs its functionality expanded by adding an option to turn off logging. The program takes a directory location as an argument, where it stores the log. I want it to not log anything if args[0] is empty. Right now the program has lines like this nested all over it:

```
DiagnosticLog.WriteLine("\t\t----Verifying Plugins were installed correctly----");
```

My first idea was to just create and do a check for a global flag within that function and run that line if it wasn't set. That way I could avoid using the same if statement around each of these lines all over the code. Is there a more clever way of just "turning off" these lines during run-time?

Comment: Is this actually anything to do with c++?

Comment: Just because my code is written in c# doesn't mean it can't be answered by someone working with c++. It can be solved in both. In fact it could probably be solved in c, as well.

Comment: Retagged to `c#` - the whole point of tags is to target your question to the right audience, please try to keep them appropriate.

Comment: It could be solved in python too, but this question is about your C# code..

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a version of `DiagnosticLog` that doesn't actually log anything, and use *it* in stead of your logging version if you don't want to log. That's assuming you know whether or not you want to log when you create the instance of `DiagnosticLog` (which I gather from the way you ask, you do).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just call a log function that checks to see if the arg is empty?

```
public void WriteLine(string log) {
    if (!firstArgIsEmpty) {
        // Print to file.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about modifying your `DiagnosticLog.WriteLine` function to take a second parameter `doActualLog` (`bool`) which has as default value `true`? Make some very minor modifications to `DiagnoticLog` to take this value into account. You can then decide at instantiation of `DiagnosticLog` if you want actual logging to happen or not.

Answer (score 1):

You could just add an `enabled` flag to `DiagnosticLog` that is `true` by default. If args[0] is empty, call `DiagnosticLog.Disable()` to set it to `false`. Then in `WriteLine` and any other logging functions, check `enabled` before doing the actual logging.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a property

```
public bool Log { get; set; }

string logFilePath;
public string LogFilePath
{
    get { return logFilePath; }
    set 
    {
        logFilePath = ValidateLogFilePath(value);
        Log = logFilePath.Length > 0;
    }            
}

public void WriteLine(string line)
{
    if (!Log)
        return;
    //...
}
```

If you make a boolean property to indicate whether logging is occuring, then you could also use it to skip other sections of code that are not necessary if logging is not occuring. This could be useful if you are building any long strings just for logging purposes.

```
if (DiagnosticLog.Log)
{
    DiagnosticLog.WriteLine("The following plugins were not installed:\r\n\t" +
          string.Join("\r\n\t", GetMissingPluginNames()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using a System.Diagnostics.TraceListener class in conjunction with a System.Diagnostics.TraceSwitch? The functionality you seem to be after is already baked in.